# Gimp: why can't I edit an image when I open it the first time

Tags: gimp

When I open Gimp on Windows and then open any image e.g. jpg, png I can't do anything with it. This happens to all files under all circumstances when I open it the first time. I've been using Gimp for 10 years+ and this problem started occurring in the past two years with all versions of Gimp since 2017+.

The only workaround is to open the image, close Gimp and then open Gimp again and open the image from "File -> Recent Images". Is there a way around this? Maybe there's a default setting in Gimp that prevents a layer from being edited that is not set when an image is opened the first time?

Comment: Recent Windows versions (Win10?) put arbitrary restrictions on "unknown" executables (and since Gimp isn't signed by Microsoft...) so it could be worth checking some security settings/white list (even if I can't explain why it would work the second time around or even why Gimp would prevent editing on a R/O image).

Comment: I can't replicate the problem using Windows 10 and recent versions of GIMP. Where did you get your copy of GIMP?  From the official GIMP site? It's really hard to answer questions like this that might depend on your system set up. Perhaps consider getting tech help from the gimpusers forum. Tech support questions are generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Could this be a variant of https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/1082 ? Check if you got any tools which might be using a fullscreen transparent window to capture events.

Comment: I don’t use any other screen tools and have the same problem on all the Windows systems I use. I didn’t think it could still be a bug after so many years, so was hoping for a simple eureka kind of answer like “switch the red screen on and off” or something like that.

Comment: Do all the systems have in common that you are installing software on them? Can you try this on one that's just got Windows and GIMP?

Comment: Gimp and Blender are the first things I install on a PC. My work PC doesn’t have Blender and it does the same thing. Various systems did this over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is to open an image, select all, copy, create a new file (or create from clipboard), then close the original and work the copy.

Comment: Thanks Joy, at least I know someone is having a similar issue.